# Is it necessary to release some resources allocated by the Python C API

Tags: python, c

I have the following C code that calls the Python API library:

```
PyObject *obj;

PyObject *arguments;

arguments = PyTuple_New(2);

PyTuple_SetItem(arguments, 0, PyLong_FromLongLong(10));

PyTuple_SetItem(arguments, 1, PyLong_FromLongLong(20));

obj = PyObject_CallObject(my_function, arguments); // should "obj" be released after being used?

PyLong_AsLongLong(obj);

Py_DECREF(arguments); // is this instruction necessary?
```

I have two questions (both are in the code as comments), namely: 1) should the variable `obj` be released after being used (if yes, how is this done?) and 2) do we need to decrease the reference counter of variable `arguments` (i.e. do we need  `Py_DECREF(arguments);`)? Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: Without the full context of the usage, it's really impossible to say.  But run your program under something like Valgrind.  If you have memory leaks that originate from where the object in question was allocated you probably need to release it.  And yes, you release objects with `Py_DECREF()`.  And if you get random crashes, you probably have either too many `Py_DECREF()` calls, or not enough `Py_INCREF()` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#objects-types-and-reference-counts, which describes the correct way to handle reference counting with the Python C API. Following the rules described there, the correct code for your situation would be the following.

```
PyObject *obj;
PyObject *arguments;
arguments = PyTuple_New(2);  // this returns a new reference

// You don't need to Py_DECREF() the return values of PyLong_FromLongLong()
// because PyTuple_SetItem() steals a reference. 
PyTuple_SetItem(arguments, 0, PyLong_FromLongLong(10));
PyTuple_SetItem(arguments, 1, PyLong_FromLongLong(20));

obj = PyObject_CallObject(my_function, arguments); // this returns a new reference

PyLong_AsLongLong(obj);

Py_DECREF(arguments); // this is necessary because a new reference was created earlier
Py_DECREF(obj); // this is necessary because a new reference was created earlier
```

Note that I have not added any error checks. Some of these functions can return `NULL` on error, so it would be wise to check for them.